# Unknown profiles icon in System Preferences

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mojave, malware

I just noticed in System Preferences a new icon "Profiles". When I click on it, it shows  'AdminPrefs' then in red letters "unsigned"  details have a lot {, (, symbols .and 'default Search Provider lines.

What is this?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot ? @s0s0

Answer (score 2):

Your MacBook is probably infected with the [OSX/Shlayer](https://www.intego.com/mac-security-blog/new-osxshlayer-malware-variant-found-using-a-dirty-new-trick/)/[Crossrider](https://blog.malwarebytes.com/threat-analysis/2018/04/new-crossrider-variant-installs-configuration-profiles-on-macs/) malware.

It's a so-called dropper which may install/already has installed additional malware.

---

Searching for a reliable removal method I came across a lot of dubious websites offering tools pretending to remove this malware. **Don't download and install them!**

Malwarebytes' [Malwarebytes 4.0](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mac-download/) or other decent AntiVirus software should be able to detect and remove this malware and subsequently loaded malware/adware.

---

Analysis: [Mitigating OSX/Shlayer](https://resources.redcanary.com/hubfs/Mitigating%20Shlayer.pdf)